# How to run nodejs spawn in a loop from exports

Tags: node.js, spawn

I am trying to stream a camera pictures continuously from a camera module. Do you know how to launch another spawn once the previous spawn finished?
Currently I am getting an error that "startCamera" function is not found once on "exit" event is executed by the child process.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
module.exports = {
cameraProcess: null,
startCamera: function () {
    var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);
    var path = require('path');
    if (isWin) {
        this.cameraProcess = spawn(path.join(__dirname, 'vfwgrab', 'VFWGrab.exe'));
    } else {
        var args = ["-w", "640", "-h", "480", "-o", "./public/stream/stream.jpg", "-t", "999999999", "-tl", "2000"];
        this.cameraProcess = spawn('raspistill', args);
    }
    this.cameraProcess.on('exit', this.loopCamera);
},
loopCamera: function (code) {
    this.startCamera(); //start the next spawn once the previous finished
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved this by moving the functions out of the exports and then referencing them in the exports. Please let me know if this is the recommended way.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cameraProcess = null;
var startCamera = function () {
  var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);
  var path = require('path');
  if (isWin) {
    this.cameraProcess = spawn(path.join(__dirname, 'vfwgrab', 'VFWGrab.exe'));
  } else {
    var args = ["-w", "640", "-h", "480", "-o", "./public/stream/stream.jpg", "-t", "999999999", "-tl", "2000"];
    this.cameraProcess = spawn('raspistill', args);
  }
  this.cameraProcess.on('exit', loopCamera);
}
var loopCamera = function (code) {
  startCamera();
}
module.exports = {
  startCamera: startCamera,
};
```